# Issues with GetProfileDataAsync after upgrade to IdentityServer3 v2.5 from v1.6.3

Tags: identityserver3

We've been running IdentityServer3 v1.x successfully over the past year, but have now upgraded to v2.5 from v1.6.3.

We have a custom UserService that implements the IUserService, so this was modified for the new context parameters and we are able to login, but are having issues with the GetProfileDataAsync

The UserService that was built for v1.6.3 works fine and we can see 12 requested claim types in `requestedClaimTypes`

```
public Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetProfileDataAsync(ClaimsPrincipal subject,
                                                        IEnumerable<string> requestedClaimTypes = null)
    {
        var userClaims = claimsService.GetByUserIdAsync(int.Parse(subject.GetSubjectId()));

        var claims =
                userClaims.Where(x => requestedClaimTypes != null && requestedClaimTypes.Contains(x.Type));
            return Task.FromResult(claims);
    }
```

But since upgrading to v2.5, the only requested claim type is sub in `context.RequestedClaimTypes`, rather than 12 we used to get. The only way to get all 12 in is to change the `AlwaysIncludeInIdToken` to `true`

Our updated UserService for v2.5 is

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        var subject = context.Subject;
        var requestedClaimTypes = context.RequestedClaimTypes;
        var userClaims = await _claimsService.GetByUserIdAsync(int.Parse(subject.GetSubjectId()));
        if (userClaims != null)
        {
            var claims = userClaims.Where(x => requestedClaimTypes != null && requestedClaimTypes.Contains(x.Type));
            context.IssuedClaims = claims;
        }
    }
```

We use SQL to store our Clients and Scopes but we've not changed any data, other than to use the IdentityServer3.EntityFramework provider

Our logging shows that the 4 scopes are being requested which have their associated scope claims as before

```js
Info: Authorize request validation success {
  "ClientId": "MyApp",
  "ClientName": "MyApp",
  "RedirectUri": "https://xxx:44300/",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "https://xxx:44300/"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "9",
  "ResponseType": "code id_token",
  "ResponseMode": "form_post",
  "Flow": "Hybrid",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile roles user",
  "State": "OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=xxxx",
  "Nonce": "xxx",
  "SessionId": "xxx",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "MyApp",
    "redirect_uri": "https://xxx:44300/",
    "response_mode": "form_post",
    "response_type": "code id_token",
    "scope": "openid profile roles user",
    "state": "OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=xxx",
    "nonce": "xxx"
  }
}
```

What do we need to do to get it to request all the claim types as before??

Comment: It works the same as before, so I suspect you had a problem with data migration of the scope claims.

Comment: @BrockAllen We've not changed anything in the ScopeClaims table. The only one that was AlwaysIncludeIdToken = true was sub, which has a scope_id of the openid scope as per the Scopes table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec says that if an access token is requested, the id_token should only contain the minimal user-related claims (aka sub). The access token can then be used to retrieve the other claims from the userinfo endpoint.

This is an optimization mechanism to keep the id_token as small as possible.

We had a bug where this was done for `id_token token` but not for `code id_token` (which is what you are using). This bug was fixed at some point along the way. I guess that is the behavioural change you are seeing.

Either set the `AlwaysIncludeInIdToken` property on the scope claims you want to be included - or use the userinfo endpoint to retrieve the claims.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We did add getting the claims from the user endpoint later yesterday in the AuthorizationCodeReceived but now we're missing the sub and amr claims which we also use

Comment: Fixed the missing sub, by readding the passed in subject claim in the `GetProfileAsync`, and fixed the amr issue with `id.AddClaim(new Claim("amr", n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("amr").Value));`